# static declaration error in iOS

Tags: ios, compiler-errors

I'm having problems figuring out how to fix this error. The following code snippet generates this error in XCode 4.2:
"**Static declaration of 'randomint' floows non-static declaration**"

```
//Returns a random integer number between low and high inclusive */
static inline int randomInt (int low, int high) {
    return (arc4random() % (high-low+1)) + low;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a line like this somewhere in your file:

```
inline int randomInt(int, int);
```

Remove it, or add static to the beginning of the declaration to look like this:

```
static inline int randomInt(int, int);
```